# Apache FTPFile permissions

Tags: java, apache, permissions, ftp

Is there a way to set *the same* permissions for a file compared to an example? I'm asking because I've only seen methods that return `boolean` on whether a particular user type can do a particular thing to a file and this incredibly inconvenient for the named purpose. The `permissions` two-dimensional array inside `FTPFile` has package visibilty, so a brute-force method would be to just access it through reflection, but my guess is, there must be some library that would add more flexibility to the Apache FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions array is always set to a 2D 3x3 array (and unless I'm missing something I can't see how that would ever change?) Knowing this you could just use the setPermission and hasPermission methods, looping from 0-3 on each one and copying the values across. It's still somewhat nasty and implementation dependant, but it doesn't rely on reflection.

Aside from that the only option I can see is subclassing FTPFile and then implementing the permissions yourself.